# Divs side by side and image span

Tags: css-float, multiple-columns

Is this behaviour somehow possible:

[image]

The structure:

```
<div class="col">
  text…
  <div class="image two-col-width"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  text…
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image two-col-width"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  text…
</div>
```

the columns are using `float`

As far as I can see this is not possible with css.
Even with multiple columns this will not work because `column-span` accept only `none` or `all`.
Is there any workaround like a javascript plugin to make this work?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You can do the text using the [columns layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns). In this case for the yellow image you would use `image{max-width: 100%}`. You can't do the image to span over 2 columns however you can do the image to span over all 3 (in this case) columns by using image{column-span: all;}

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed not possible to do it with floats only because the float columns can't track or calculate the size of the colored divs going cross column. However this is easily achievable with Flexbox.